# Divide values in a column by the value of the column name

Tags: python, pandas

So let's say you have a DataFrame, which has column names/values [1,2,3,4]. Now I want to divide every value in the dataframe by the value of the column (the columns represent numerical values). I could do it with a for loop, but I'd rather do it with a lambda function but I could not find how and could not figure it out with the standard explanations of the working of lambda functions. The version with the for-loop works, but I'm afraid it won't scale well when the dataframe becomes larger. This is what I already have:

```
values = df.columns #or predefined array, does not really matter in this case
for i in range(len(values)):
    df[values[i]] = df[values[i]] / values[i]
print(df.head())
```

Comment: Don't use a lambda function; use the PANDAS vectorized facilities, those whole-column operations.  Any PANDAS tutorial introduces these.  If you get stuck, *then* post a question with the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
Please [include a minimal data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have this dataframe:

```
   10  20  30
0   1   1   1
1   2   2   2
2   3   3   3
```

Then you can use [`.divide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.divide.html#pandas-dataframe-divide) to divide the dataframe:

```
print(df.divide(df.columns.astype(float)))
```

Prints:

```
    10    20        30
0  0.1  0.05  0.033333
1  0.2  0.10  0.066667
2  0.3  0.15  0.100000
```